# Command "python setup.py egg_info"

Tags: python

I've finished installing Python on server, When I try to install any package I keep getting this error message :

```
   Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
      File "setuptools/__init__.py", line 132
        for k in set(_incl) & set(attrs)
          ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-0keyyz/setuptools
```

does any one know how to fix this please ?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```sh
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install setuptools
pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

If you're on Linux, use pip3 instead of pip, so add a 3 after pip

Comment: I already tried that and still have the same error ...

Comment: Are you using pip3?

Comment: ```Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages```this the message I get but I've installed the lastest python version 3.8

Comment: You're using pip and python 2, use pip3 install setuptools --upgrade

Answer (score 0):

You have an out of date version of `setuptools`

upgrade setuptools running following command and try installing your packages again.:

`pip install --upgrade setuptools`

Note: also try installing dev packages for your specific python version:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev libmysqlclient-dev   # for python3.6
```

Comment: I already tried that and still have the same error ...

Comment: are you sure you got the error while installing any package?

Comment: If you look at the my message the first error is when I try pip install --upgrade setuptools @Tasnuva

Comment: Im using last python version